# Why are redirected URLs displayed in SERP?

Tags: seo, url, search-results, 302-redirect, affiliate

I use a permalink redirect mode for affiliate links. Something similar to `www.example.com/out/google` → this will 302 redirect to `google.com`.

All these redirected URLs display in search using the title and the meta description of the landing URL.

I need to note that these URLs use 302 method and they are nofollowed.

Does this affect my website in any way in terms of SEO (possibly duplicate content issues)?

Comment: Maybe this question will help you? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87730/redirected-urls-show-in-serp-with-the-original-permalink-but-with-the-title-and

Comment: What are you searching for to return these URLs in the SERPs? If you are using a `site:` search then this behaviour is not uncommon. But a `site:` search is not a "normal" web search.